# How can I replace springloaded jar in Grails installation

Tags: grails, groovy

My Grails 2.1.5 app throws exception java.lang.ClassCastException: java.beans.WeakIdentityMap. This seems to be a known problem, and the resolution advised on some forums is to replace springloaded jar version 1.1.1 with 1.1.2 (or to downgrade the java version, which I would rather not do)

How can I do that? I tried replacing the jar in Grails installation lib directory, and I got:

Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:/grails-2.1.5/lib/org.springs
ource.springloaded/springloaded-core/jars/springloaded-core-1.1.1.jar

So it's still looking for the old 1.1.1 jar file.

Please advise

Comment: I suppose you have to rename 1.1.2 jar to 1.1.1 in the lib. Grails 2.1.5 will always look for v1.1.1 as it is preset as a dependency.

Comment: And there is no way to configure the jars that Grails is looking for?

Comment: you could try to pass the desired version by `GRAILS_OPTS`.  be sure to disable the reloading done automaticlly.  e.g. `GRAILS_OPTS="-javaagent:$HOME/.gvm/grails/2.4.2/lib/org.springframework/springloaded/jars/springloaded-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar -Xverify:none  -noverify -Dspringloaded.synchronize=true -Djdk.reflect.allowGetCallerClass=true -Dspringloaded=profile=grails;cacheDir=/tmp/slcache" grails run-app`

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this for Grails 3.1.8, I downloaded `springloaded-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar` and just replaced it in `<GRAILS_HOME>\lib\org.springframework\springloaded\jars` after backing up the previous 1.2.6 version.