# Grails IntelliJ run-app loader constraint violation

Tags: intellij-idea, grails

First of all: I have no experience with grails and groovy.

I have a legacy project based on Grails 2.4.5, and have a problem with running it from IntelliJ.

> Error executing script RunApp: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.getReloadableType(II)Lorg/springsource/loaded/ReloadableType;" the class loader (instance of java/net/URLClassLoader) of the current class, Config, and the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/springsource/loaded/TypeRegistry, have different Class objects for the type org/springsource/loaded/ReloadableType used in the signature (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

However when I try to run it manually by: "grails run-app" it runs without a problem.

I tried creating an empty project in IntelliJ and it compiles and runs.

I've wasted 5 hours already trying to compare empty project and mine and found no clue. What should I check?

Comment: Make sure to use at max a jdk8 and if that alone does not help, check out how to replace springloaded with grails (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000803/how-can-i-replace-springloaded-jar-in-grails-installation - there might be better explanations out there)

Comment: I am using OpenJDK 1.8 and SDK is installed by sdkman on ubuntu. The project has explicit dependence `runtime "org.springframework:springloaded:1.2.3.RELEASE"`, and this file is present in sdk's lib directory

Comment: This version is very old and your JDK is most likely very new.  Try the latest snapshot of springloaded first.  Also if you run in intellij look at the first line in the console there (it's grayed out and folded).  Unfold and check the command that is actually run.  Intellij does it's thing and usually don't get things right. I'd just use `grails run-app` and look into remote debugging (assuming, that this is what you are after anyway)